# Select only matching zipcodes with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display only zipcodes that multiple people have in my table and sort it by ascending order.

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes" FROM people GROUP BY zipcode ORDER BY ASC;
```

Comment: What does "ascending order" mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes", count(1) as ZIP_COUNT
FROM people 
GROUP BY zipcode 
ORDER BY ZIP_COUNT ASC;
```

If you only need zipcode that appears 2+ times append (before the order) :

```
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Or (if Mysql supports aliases in HAVING clause) :

```
HAVING ZIP_COUNT > 1
```

Comment: where do I add HAVING?

Comment: before the ORDER BY (after the GROUP BY)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your query is that you didn't specify any column in the order by sections.

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes" FROM people GROUP BY zipcode ORDER BY ASC;
```

So just add the zipcode to it and it will be good.

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes" FROM people GROUP BY zipcode ORDER BY zipcode ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query selects zipcode(s) having multiple entries in table "people":

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes" 
FROM people 
GROUP BY zipcode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY zipcode ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT zipcode AS "zipcodes", count(zipcode) as noofzip
FROM people 
GROUP BY zipcode 
having count(zipcode)>1
order by zipcode
```